# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting below exception at the end of 200+ test case execution. As this is failing in the last stage of the test suite execution - Testng reports are not created.

Tried all the options - used `driver.quit()`, `driver.close()`, freshly installed `FF 45 ESR` version but no luck!!

Note -> Exception occurs at the end of test suite execution (which has 21 test classes).

Realised later that only one test case is throwing this exeption. (Strange that it allowed whole suite to run till the end)

My test class is here -

```
@DataProvider (name = "inputData")
    public Object[][] inputData(){

        return new Object[][] {{passwordPolicyPage.minLengthTextBox,"9"},{passwordPolicyPage.minLowerCaseTextBox,"2"},
                               {passwordPolicyPage.minSplCharsTextBox,"2"},{passwordPolicyPage.minUpperCaseTextBox,"2"},
                               {passwordPolicyPage.notLastPswdsTextBox,"2"},{passwordPolicyPage.pswdExpDaysTextBox,"2"},
                               {passwordPolicyPage.maxBadAttemptsTextBox,"2"},{passwordPolicyPage.notUsedInMonthsCaseTextBox,"2"}};
    }

    @Test(testName = "TS#-6552,TS#-6556,TS#-6549,TS#-6553,TS#-6550,TS#-6554,TS#-6551,TS#-6555,TS#-6928", groups = { "Sanity" },dataProvider = "inputData")
    public void testEditPswdPolicy(WebElement textBox, String value) {

        if (!passwordPolicyPage.checkBox.isSelected())
            CommonOperations.click(passwordPolicyPage.checkBox);
        CommonOperations.click(passwordPolicyPage.enabledEditPolicyBtn);
        CommonOperations.waitUntilElementAppears(passwordPolicyPage.editPolicyContent, driver);

        CommonOperations.enterData(textBox, value);
        CommonOperations.click(passwordPolicyPage.saveBtn);

        CommonOperations.sleep(1000);

        CommonOperations.click(passwordPolicyPage.enabledEditPolicyBtn);
        CommonOperations.waitUntilElementAppears(passwordPolicyPage.editPolicyContent, driver);

        try{
        Assert.assertEquals(CommonOperations.getValue(textBox, "value"), value, "Changes were not saved for "+CommonOperations.getValue(textBox, "class")+"!!!!");
        }catch(AssertionError e){
            CommonOperations.click(passwordPolicyPage.cancelBtn);
            CommonOperations.sleep(1000);
            Assert.assertTrue(false, "Changes were not saved for "+CommonOperations.getValue(textBox, "class")+"!!!!");
        }
    }

@AfterClass (alwaysRun = true)
    public void close(){
        try{
        driver.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
```

Whole exception error :-

> [testng] Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called.
>          [testng] Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
>          [testng] System info: host: 'dell-PC', ip: '192.168.33.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
>          [testng] Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>          [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:377)
>          [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
>          [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
>          [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
>          [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
>          [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
>          [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:59)
>          [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:37)
>          [testng]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.toString(Unknown Source)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.generateTable(TestHTMLReporter.java:114)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.generateLog(TestHTMLReporter.java:305)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.onFinish(TestHTMLReporter.java:40)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.fireEvent(TestRunner.java:1241)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:1032)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
>          [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
>          [testng] The tests failed.

Comment: Could you share your code how are you using `WebDriver.quit()`?? May be you are using `WebDriver` instance further after calling `.quit()` as exception clearly states..:)

Comment: In which line you are getting error? May this be for those sleep statements can you check? Somehow sleep timingout your sessions?

Comment: Strange thing is , it does not show at what point it is failing. Test case failures are genuine though. And failures are assertion failures.